# Expecting datatype compatibility error packed vs unpacked array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to design a matrix multiplier using systolic arrays architecture. The inputs are 1D arrays with 2's complement 16bits elements. Here is my code:

```
 `timescale 1 ns/ 1 ps

module sys_array_tb;

reg reset, clk;
localparam  M = 2;
localparam  N = 2;
localparam  DW = 16;

reg start;
reg signed [DW-1:0] W [M*N-1:0];
reg signed [DW-1:0] X [M*N-1:0];
wire signed [DW*2:0] Y [M-1:0];
wire done;

systolic_array #(.M(M),.N(N), .DW(DW)) uut(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), 
                                    .start(start), .X(X),.W(W),.done(done), .Y());

initial begin
    reset <= 1;
  clk <= 0;
  #3
  reset <= 0;
  #3
  
  

  W = {16'h0234, 16'h1345, 16'h2456, 16'h3567};
  X = {16'h0234, 16'h1345, 16'h2456, 16'h3567};
  
  start = 1;
  #3


  wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {16'h1234, 16'h2345, 16'h3456, 16'h4567};
  X = {16'h1234, 16'h2345, 16'h3456, 16'h4567};
  
  wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {16'h2234, 16'h3345, 16'h4456, 16'h5567};
  X = {16'h2234, 16'h3345, 16'h4456, 16'h5567};

   wait(done);
  
  #3

  W = {16'h3234, 16'h4345, 16'h5456, 16'h6567};
  X = {16'h3234, 16'h4345, 16'h5456, 16'h6567};
   
   wait(done);

end

initial begin
    repeat(100)
        #5 clk <= ~clk;
end

initial begin
    $dumpfile("wave.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, sys_array_tb);
end



endmodule


module systolic_array #(
    parameter M = 2,
    parameter N = 2,
    parameter DW = 16
)
(
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input start, // start of the process
  output reg done,
  
  input signed [DW-1:0] W [M*N-1:0],
  input signed [DW-1:0] X [M*N-1:0],
  output signed [2*DW:0] Y [M-1:0]
);


reg calc_done;

reg signed [DW-1:0] A_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0];
reg signed [DW-1:0] B_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0];
reg signed [2*DW:0] C_reg [M-1:0][N-1:0]; 



integer m,n;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  // initializing
  if(reset) begin
    m = 0;
    n = 0 ;
    calc_done = 0;
    done = 0;
    //  count <= 0;
    for(m=0;m<=2;m=m+1) begin
      for(n=0;n<=2;n=n+1) begin
        A_reg[m][n] = 16'd0;
        B_reg[m][n] = 16'd0;
        C_reg[m][n] = 33'd0;
        end 
      end 
  end
  else begin
    if (start) begin
      // converting 1D array to 2D
      for(m=0;m<=M;m=m+1) begin
        for(n=0;n<=N;n=n+1) begin
          A_reg[m][n] = W[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
          B_reg[m][n] = X[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
          C_reg[m][n] = 33'd0;
        end 
      end

      if(!calc_done) begin
        C_reg[m][n] = res[m][n];
        if(n == N) begin
          n = 0;
            if (m == M) begin
              m = 0;
              calc_done = 1;
            end
            else m = m + 1;
        end
        else n = n + 1;       
      end else if(calc_done) begin
        // converting 2D array to 1D
        for(m=0;m<=2;m=m+1) begin   //run through the rows
          for(n=0;n<=2;n=n+1) begin    //run through the columns
            Y[(m*M+n)*16+:16] = C_reg[m][n];
          end
        end   
        done = 1; 
      end

    end    
  end
end

wire [DW-1:0] a_ins [M-1:0][N:0];
wire [DW-1:0] b_ins [M:0][N-1:0];
wire [2*DW:0] c_outs [M-1:0][N-1:0];
wire [2*DW:0] res [M-1:0][N-1:0];
    

genvar  i,j;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i+1) //: Rows
  begin
    for (j = 0; j < N; j = j+1) // : Columns
    begin
      PE #(.DW(DW)) pe (
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset),
        .x_i(a_ins[i][j]),
        .y_i(b_ins[i][j]),
        .x_o(a_ins[i][j+1]),
        .y_o(b_ins[i+1][j]),
        .mac(c_outs[i][j])
      );
    end
  end
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i +1) begin
     assign  a_ins[i][0] = A_reg[i][0];
  end
  for (j = 0; j < N; j = j +1) begin
     assign b_ins[0][j] = B_reg[0][j];
  end
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i +1) begin
     for (j = 0; j < N; j = j +1) begin
        assign res[i][j] = c_outs[i][j];
     end
  end
endgenerate

endmodule

module PE #(
    parameter DW = 16
)
(
input clk,
input reset,

input signed[DW-1:0] x_i,
input signed[DW-1:0] y_i,

output signed[DW-1:0] x_o,
output signed[DW-1:0] y_o,
output signed[2*DW:0] mac // multiply and accumulate 

);


reg signed[DW-1:0] x_reg,y_reg;
reg signed[2*DW:0] mac_reg;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (reset) begin
    x_reg <= 0;
    y_reg <= 0;  
    mac_reg <= 0;
  end else begin
    x_reg <= x_i;
    y_reg <= y_i;
    mac_reg <= mac_reg + (x_reg * y_reg);
  end
end

assign x_o = x_reg;
assign y_o = y_reg;
assign mac = mac_reg;

endmodule
```

I'm getting the following errors when running the simulation:

```
A_reg[m][n] = W[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
                        |
ncelab: *E,TYCMPAT (./mult.sv,126|24): assignment operator type check failed (expecting datatype compatible with 'packed array' but found 'unpacked array [15:0] of signed packed array [15:0] of logic' instead).
          A_reg[m][n] = W[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
                        |
ncelab: *W,BNDMEM (./mult.sv,126|24): Memory index out of declared bounds.
          B_reg[m][n] = X[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
                        |
ncelab: *E,TYCMPAT (./mult.sv,127|24): assignment operator type check failed (expecting datatype compatible with 'packed array' but found 'unpacked array [15:0] of signed packed array [15:0] of logic' instead).
          B_reg[m][n] = X[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
                        |
ncelab: *W,BNDMEM (./mult.sv,127|24): Memory index out of declared bounds.
            Y[(m*M+n)*16+:16] = C_reg[m][n];
            |
ncelab: *W,BNDMEM (./mult.sv,146|12): Memory index out of declared bounds.
            Y[(m*M+n)*16+:16] = C_reg[m][n];
                                        |
ncelab: *E,TYCMPAT (./mult.sv,146|40): assignment operator type check failed (expecting datatype compatible with 'unpacked array [15:0] of signed packed array [32:0] of logic' but found 'packed array' instead).
```

I might miss something obvious, but I'm not sure how get to these datatypes match. Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the error message, in the following assignment:

```
      A_reg[m][n] = W[(m*M+n)*16+:16];
```

set m=n=0:

```
      A_reg[0][0] = W[0 +: 16];
```

which is the same as:

```
      A_reg[0][0] = W[15:0];
```

That expression for `W` does not make sense.

With M=N=2, the input declaration resolves to:

```
input signed [15:0] W [3:0],
```

That is an array of 4 16-bit values.  Let's assume you want the following 4 16-bit assignments:

```
  A_reg[0][0] = W[0];
  A_reg[0][1] = W[1];
  A_reg[1][0] = W[2];
  A_reg[1][1] = W[3];
```

Then, this would be the `for` loop:

```
  for(m=0;m<=M;m=m+1) begin
    for(n=0;n<=N;n=n+1) begin
      A_reg[m][n] = W[ (2*m) + n ];
```

This resolves the error message for that line of code.